# Magnetic field of a wire with over 1000 amperes?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Does a large thick wire that has over 1000 amperes of current flowing 
through it generate powerful magnetic fields?

What formula is best here to predict $B$?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Direction of Magnetic force from a current running through a coil of wire](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7633/)

Comment: You can use the formula at http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magcur.html